# How to solve the equation $\exp(3t) - \exp(2t) = A$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got into a problem while deriving a solution for my system.

I've ended up with equation $$\exp(3t) - \exp(2t) = A$$, where $A$ is some constant.
I'm fine with numeric solution but I kinda can't figure out a way to solve this analytically, so I'd like to humbly ask for help or some advice, if there is any?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Analytically, it's a cubic equation for $exp(t)$ which can be solved using Cardano's formula.

Comment: **HINT**: make change of variables $$x = \exp(t)$$ and solve the resulting polynomial for zeros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$e^{3t}-e^{2t}=(e^{t})^3-(e^t)^2=A$$
Now set $z=e^t$
$$z^3-z^2=A$$
$$z^3-z^2-A=0$$
at which you solve for A using one of the equations for cubical solutions and then you have
$$t=\ln z$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks I'm gonna beat my head against a wall, that I didn't realize this sooner.. :-), Again, thanks.

Comment: No worries man! :) It's easy to get blinded in something

Answer (score 2):

Setting $x=e^t$, the equation turns to

$$x^3-x^2=A,$$ with $x>0$.

Such a cubic equation can be solved using the [Cardano's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).

As you can check from the plot of the function $x^3-x^2$, there are two solutions in range $[0,1]$ (i.e. $t<0$) for $-\dfrac4{27}<A<0$ and one in range $[1,\infty]$ (i.e. $t>0$) for $A>0$.

Comment: Crossed with Zelos and Vlad.